# append only if part of word is not already in list

Tags: python, list, character

I have a list like the following and want to make two lists out of it. If the first one contains S01_a, S01_b should be in the second list.

```
my_list = ['S01_a', 'S01_b', 'S02_a', 'S02_b', 'S03_a', 'S03_b', 'S04_a', 'S04_b']
```

I tried this, but I don't know how to refer to the [1:2] characters of the items in list1. Has anyone a solution?

```
stims = ["S01_a", "S01_b", "S02_a", "S02_b", "S03_a", "S03_b", "S04_a", "S04_b"]

l1 = []
l2 = []
for item in stims:
    if item[1:2] not in l1:
        l1.append(item)
    else:
        l2.append(item)


print(l1)
print(l2)
```

The output is:

```
['S01_a', 'S01_b', 'S02_a', 'S02_b', 'S03_a', 'S03_b', 'S04_a', 'S04_b']
[]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you add your output?

Comment: Are you looking for `l1, l2 = stims[::2], stims[1::2]`?

Comment: Just for info [1:2] is the same same as [1]. You are specifying starting at index 1, up to but not including 2 (i.e 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any()` with a generator that tests `item[1:3]` against each element of the list.

```
for item in stims:
    if not any(item[1:3] == el[1:3] for el in l1):
        l1.append(item)
    else:
        l2.append(item)
```

You need to use the slice `[1:3]`. Remember, the second index is not inclusive, so `[1:2]` just selects the digit `0`, not the two digits `01`, `02`, etc.

Comment: This append only 'S01_a' to the first list but then everything else to the second

Comment: It should be `[1:3]`. `[1:2]` just matches the `0`, not `01`.